# How to pass data to different templates using *ngFor and *ngIf Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an object like below

```
let obj = [{
    templateId: 1,
    name: "Template 1"
}, {
    templateId: 2,
    name: "Template 1"
}, {
    templateId: 3,
    name: "Template 1"
}];
```

In HTML Template, I'm trying to pass data to different templates based on the tempalteId like below

```
<div *ngFor="let tmpl of obj">
    <div *ngIf="tmpl.templateId == 1; else templateTwo; context: tmpl">
        {{ tmpl.name }}
    </div>
</div>
<ng-template #templateTwo let-data="data">
    <div *ngIf="data.templateId == 2; else templateThree; context: data">
        {{ data.name }}
    </div>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #templateThree let-data="data">
    <div *ngIf="data.templateId == 3">
        {{ data.name }}
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

In the above html template, based on the templateId I want to pass the data to that respective template, but I am unable to do that as it throwing error in the template code, what is the wrong I am doing here.

Please let me know the right way.

Comment: Please post what error you are getting?..

Comment: @Raghav I am getting respective error **Can't bind to 'ngIfContext' since it isn't a known property of 'div'**

Comment: What is `let-data="data"` and where it comes from. Can you post `data` object as well?????

Comment: I want to pass data to template when if condition is not satisfied. To pass the data I 've used let-data="data"

Answer (score 1):

you can use *ngTemplateOutlet directive on a ng-container element to pass your context to your desired template without changing your html structure :

```
<div *ngFor="let tmpl of obj">

   <div *ngIf="tmpl.templateId == 1">
      {{ tmpl.name }}
   </div>

   <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="templateTwo; context: tmpl"></ng-container>
   <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="templateThree; context: tmpl"></ng-container>

</div>

<ng-template #templateTwo  let-id="templateId" let-name="name">
   <div *ngIf="id == 2">
        {{ name }}
   </div> 
</ng-template>

<ng-template #templateThree  let-id="templateId" let-name="name">
   <div *ngIf="id == 3">
        {{ name }}
   </div> 
</ng-template>
```

[example code on stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-csk5le?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

you can also put your ng-templates directly inside div with ngFor and simply use the same input variable you declared in your ngFor statment like this:

```
  <div *ngFor="let tmpl of obj">

    <div *ngIf="tmpl.templateId == 1; else templateTwo">
        {{ tmpl.name }}
    </div>

    <ng-template #templateTwo >
      <div *ngIf="tmpl.templateId == 2; else templateThree; ">
          {{ tmpl.name }}
      </div>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template #templateThree >
        <div *ngIf="tmpl.templateId == 3">
            {{ tmpl.name }}
        </div>
    </ng-template>

  </div>
```

Comment: Hadi Golkarian, your answer works, but, can we do without using ng-templates? because I've set widths for every divisons which shouldn't change. If I use ***ngIf** templates will load dynamically

Answer (score 0):

If i correctly understand your question and if you don't want to use `ng-template` then you can code like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let tmpl of obj">

    <div *ngIf="tmpl.templateId == 1">
        ...
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="tmpl.templateId == 2">
        ...
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="tmpl.templateId == 3">
        ...
    </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who might stumble on it in future, my suggestion would be to solve it by using `ng-container` with an **expression** (assigned to `*ngTemplateOutlet=`) that resolves with the name of the ng-template to use for the current object of the array being iterated.

```
<ng-template #templateOne let-tmpl="tmp">
  <div>
    {{ tmpl.name }}
  </div>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #templateTwo let-data="tmp">
  <div>
    {{ data.name }}
  </div>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #templateThree let-data="tmp">
  <div>
    {{ data.name }}
  </div>
</ng-template>

<div *ngFor="let tmpl of obj">
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="tmpl.templateId == 1 ? templateOne :
    tmpl.templateId == 2 ? templateTwo : templateThree; context: {tmp: tmpl}"></ng-container>
</div>
```